# Finding the basis for a subspace of all $3 \times 3$ matrices with zero trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, trace

I am interested in verifying that my understanding of the basis for $3 \times 3$ (or even $n \times n$ matrices) that have a trace $= 0$ is along the right path.

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
With the above $3 \times 3$ matrix with trace $0$ know that

$a + e + i = 0$

$a = -e - i$

$e = -i -a$

$i = -a -e$

Outside of the elementary bases making up everything except the diagonal, I thought my last basis was

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -e-i & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -i-a & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -a-e \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

But by inspection, this does not seem to account for the instance where one of the diagonals is 0 and the other two are not.

My last consideration that I think is more accurate would be splitting the above matrix into the following combinations:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -a & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -a & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & a \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

But this also doesn't feel quite correct. I feel I am close but missing one additional consideration.

I have also found other posts concerning the dimensions like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066824/find-the-dimension-of-the-space-of-4-times-4-real-matrices-with-zero-trace), but there was never a concrete basis provided to go off of.

Thanks!

Comment: A basis for this space will be a set of eight matrices. I don't see anything like that in your question.

Comment: What is unclear from the accepted answer from your linked post?

Comment: I suggest you use \pmatrix in place of \matrix

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The other elementary matrices that do not make up the diagonal I understand, it is the last matrices that complete the basis that account for values in the diagonal I am unsure of how to find.

Comment: Do you know how to find a basis for the nullspace of a general linear transformation?  You can use the same process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your matrix, there is only a single constraint.

Your problem have $9$ variables and $1$ constraint.

$$a+e+i = 0$$

The nullity is $9-1=8$.

In general the matrix can be written as

\begin{bmatrix} -e-i & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix}

Let me write out a few elements of the possible basis, by observing the places where $e$ appears, we can choose

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

By observing places where $i$ appears, we can choose

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

By observing places where $b$ appears, we can choose

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Try to find the other $5$ elements.

Comment: When you observe places where i appears, would it not be -1 at (1,1) and 1 at (3,3)?

Comment: oops, thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition on trace makes the space to be an $8$ dimensional space. For a basis you may try  $$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

and  $$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1& 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

and the other $6$ elementary basis matrices whose diagonal elements are $0$